I made a logic which collects data from firestore documents of all clients and generates different pdf for each clients but it only generates one pdf
The loop is expected to iterate for the total number of clients but exits after generating a pdf for one client:
private void generatePdf() {
    firestore.collection("Users").document(userId).collection("Clients").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                int totalClients = task.getResult().size();
                final int[] processedClients = {0};

                for (DocumentSnapshot clientDocument : task.getResult()) {
                    clientDocumentId = clientDocument.getId();
                    firestore.collection("Users").document(userId).collection("Clients").document(clientDocumentId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                clientName = document.getString("ClientName");
                                clientArea = document.getString("ClientArea");
                                PdfDocument myPdfDocument = new PdfDocument();

                                firestore.collection("Users").document(userId).collection("Clients").document(clientDocumentId).collection("Orders").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            List<Double> totalJugAmountList = new ArrayList<>();
                                            List<Double> totalBottleAmountList = new ArrayList<>();

                                            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                                Double totalJugAmount = Double.valueOf(document.getString("CoolJugIn"));
                                                Double totalBottleAmount = Double.valueOf(document.getString("NormalBottleIn"));

                                                if (totalJugAmount != null && totalBottleAmount != null) {
                                                    totalJugAmountList.add(totalJugAmount);
                                                    totalBottleAmountList.add(totalBottleAmount);
                                                }
                                            }

                                            totalJugs = (int) sumPayments(totalJugAmountList);
                                            totalBottle = (int) sumPayments(totalBottleAmountList);
                                            int tempJugAmount = totalJugs * jugPrice;
                                            jugAmount = formatIndianNumber(totalJugs * jugPrice);
                                            int tempBottleAmount = (totalBottle * jugPrice);
                                            bottleAmount = formatIndianNumber(totalBottle * jugPrice);
                                            totalAmount = String.valueOf(tempJugAmount + tempBottleAmount);

                                            Paint myPaint = new Paint();
                                            Paint senderPaint = new Paint();
                                            monthNumber = currentMonth;
                                            monthName = getMonthName(monthNumber);

                                            PdfDocument.PageInfo myPageInfo1 = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(1360, 2760, 1).create();
                                            PdfDocument.Page myPage1 = myPdfDocument.startPage(myPageInfo1);
                                            Canvas canvas = myPage1.getCanvas();
                                            canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBmp, 800, 70, myPaint);
                                            canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBmp1, 800, 1400, myPaint);
                                            senderPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
                                            senderPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
                                            senderPaint.setTextSize(40);
                                            senderPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(DashboardActivity.this, R.color.secondaryDarkText));
                                            canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(totalJugs), 60, 170, senderPaint);
                                            canvas.drawText("Company Name,", 60, 220, senderPaint);

                                            myPdfDocument.finishPage(myPage1);
                                            String directory_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Company Name/" + monthName + " " + currentYear + "/";
                                            File file = new File(directory_path);

                                            if (!file.exists()) {
                                                file.mkdirs();
                                            }

                                            String targetPdf = directory_path + clientName + ".pdf";
                                            File filePath = new File(targetPdf);

                                            try {
                                                myPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
                                                Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Pdf Generated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            } finally {
                                                myPdfDocument.close(); // Close the document after writing to it
                                                processedClients[0]++;

                                                // Check if all clients have been processed
                                                if (processedClients[0] == totalClients) {
                                                    // All clients processed, do something if needed
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


try to log targetPdf and see what you get in log... may be same is coming for all customers...

This Code Worked for Me
private void generatePdf() {
    firestore.collection("Users").document(userId).collection("Clients").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot clientDocument : task.getResult()) {
                    String clientDocumentId = clientDocument.getId();
                    String clientName = clientDocument.getString("ClientName");
                    String clientArea = clientDocument.getString("ClientArea");

                    firestore.collection("Users").document(userId).collection("Clients").document(clientDocumentId).collection("Orders").whereEqualTo("Month", String.valueOf(currentMonth)).whereEqualTo("Year", String.valueOf(currentYear)).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                List<Double> totalJugAmountList = new ArrayList<>();
                                List<Double> totalBottleAmountList = new ArrayList<>();

                                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                    Double totalJugAmount = Double.valueOf(document.getString("CoolJugIn"));
                                    Double totalBottleAmount = Double.valueOf(document.getString("NormalBottleIn"));

                                    if (totalJugAmount != null && totalBottleAmount != null) {
                                        totalJugAmountList.add(totalJugAmount);
                                        totalBottleAmountList.add(totalBottleAmount);
                                    }
                                }

                                int totalJugs = (int) sumPayments(totalJugAmountList);
                                int totalBottle = (int) sumPayments(totalBottleAmountList);
                                int tempJugAmount = totalJugs * jugPrice;
                                String jugAmount = formatIndianNumber(totalJugs * jugPrice);
                                int tempBottleAmount = (totalBottle * jugPrice);
                                String bottleAmount = formatIndianNumber(totalBottle * jugPrice);
                                String totalAmount = String.valueOf(tempJugAmount + tempBottleAmount);
                                PdfDocument myPdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
                                Paint myPaint = new Paint();
                                Paint senderPaint = new Paint();
                                int monthNumber = currentMonth;
                                String monthName = getMonthName(monthNumber);

                                PdfDocument.PageInfo myPageInfo1 = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(1360, 2760, 1).create();
                                PdfDocument.Page myPage1 = myPdfDocument.startPage(myPageInfo1);
                                Canvas canvas = myPage1.getCanvas();
                                canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBmp, 800, 70, myPaint);
                                canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBmp1, 800, 1400, myPaint);
                                senderPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
                                senderPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
                                senderPaint.setTextSize(40);
                                senderPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(DashboardActivity.this, R.color.secondaryDarkText));
                                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(totalJugs), 60, 170, senderPaint);
                                canvas.drawText("Company Name,", 60, 220, senderPaint);

                                myPdfDocument.finishPage(myPage1);
                                String directory_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Company Name/" + monthName + " " + currentYear + "/";
                                File file = new File(directory_path);

                                if (!file.exists()) {
                                    file.mkdirs();
                                }

                                String targetPdf = directory_path + clientName + ".pdf";
                                File filePath = new File(targetPdf);

                                try {
                                    myPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
                                    Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Pdf Generated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                myPdfDocument.close(); // Close the document after writing to it

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
